# star pattern using ternary operator

Tags: php

```
<?php
for ($row = 1; $row <= $_POST["number"]; $row++)
{
for ($col = 1; $col <= ($row >= ($_POST["number"]/2) ? ($_POST["number"]+1)- $row : $row); $col++)
    {
        echo '* ';
    }

     echo "<br>";
}
print(json_encode(count($row)));

?>
```

the question is to print the pattern and also the total number of stars in each row.
i tried degugging my self but if i change the condition and only for some inputs the answer is correct.
[image: final]

Comment: What exactly you want ?

Comment: i guess my condion is wrong but dont know what is wrong @JohnDoe

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
<?php
$_POST["number"] = 10;
$row_num = array();
for ($row = 1; $row <= $_POST["number"]; $row++)
{
    $count = 0;
    for ($col = 1; $col <= ($row >= ($_POST["number"]/2) ? ($_POST["number"]+1)- $row : $row); $col++)
    {
        $count++;
        echo '* ';
    }
    echo "<br>";
    array_push($row_num, $count);
}
print_r ($row_num);
?>
```